# Flash Upload - There has been an I/O Error : Error #2038

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

I know this is already asked question and possible to be closed or to be tag as duplicate question, But i need a solution about this problem.

I am creating website with uploading, I downloaded and used this **Multiple File Upload With Progress Bar Using Flash and ASP.NET**.

[Multiple File Upload With Progress Bar Using Flash and ASP.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15742/%2FArticles%2F15742%2FMultiple-File-Upload-With-Progress-Bar-Using-Flash)

I already tried everything what I've searched in the internet, Like **changing the file upload size**, **give permission**, **modify the web.config**, **changing browser**, **download latest flash player**, **etc.**.

All of that solution is not working for me.

[image: This is the error when i click upload.]
[image: after clicking ok, this is what I've got.]

Any ideas what is the exactly issue why i'm getting this error.

Comment: You can check both HTTP request and response using tracer e.g. Fiddler, and provide example code used in the process.